Player touches ball down in the in goal after being tackled
If a defending player is tackled in their own in goal area is play stopped when the ball touches the ground providing the defender is still holding it i.e. is this treated as a touchdown in which case the game is restarted with either a goal line dropout for the defending team or a 5 meter scrum to the attacking team depending on how the ball was played in.

I don't see what part of the Q&A you already know about is difficult. Please do not post another question unless you can clearly identify its difference from any existing post.

Hi @Nij, it is a different question?

Attacker plays ball into in-goal. Defender makes ball dead. How is this not the same question as the duplicate?
